# Computed property for one of the records in one-to-many relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My datamodel is a sample, which has many analyses on it. (Think of a sample that can be analyzed multiple times.)

I would like to create a computed property on the sample model that grabs one of the analyses based on some criteria and then maybe display that one analysis in my template. The part that has me confused is that the many part is not just a property, but a promise, so I am not really sure how to work with it in my computed property and how to display it in my template.

My datamodels are below:

```
// Define datamodels
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Sample = DS.Model.extend({
  note: attr('string'),
  region: attr('string'),
  timeCollected: attr('string'),
  sampleID: attr('string'),
  category: attr('string'),
  approach: attr('string'),
  team: attr('string'),
  location: attr('string'),
  medium: attr('string'),
  instrument: attr('string'),
  asset: attr('string'),
  mission: attr('string'),
  analyses: DS.hasMany('analysis', {async: true}),

  mostImportantAnalysis: function(){
    var analysesPromise = this.get('analyses'); 

    // NOW WHAT ???

    return importantAnalysis.get('result');
  }.property('analyses')  
});

App.Analysis = DS.Model.extend({
  result: attr('string'),   
  timeAnalyzed: attr('string'), 
  method: attr('string'),
  agent: attr('string'),
  sample: DS.belongsTo('sample', { async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to wait for the promise to resolve first... Below is what ended up working for me:

```
mostImportantAnalysis: function(){
  var result = "";

  // Make sure the promise resolves before returning
  var analyses = this.get('analyses');
  if(!analyses.get("isFulfilled")) {
    return "";
  }

  result = analyses.objectAt(0).get('result');

  return result;
}.property('analyses.@each.result')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the promise as if it was a properly loaded object -

```
mostImportantAnalysis: function(){
  var analyses = this.get('analyses'); 

  //For example, to get the analysis with the lowest/highest time:
  mostImportantAnalysis = analyses.sortBy('timeAnalyzed')[0]

  return mostImportantAnalysis.get('result');
}.property('analyses.@each.timeAnalyzed')
```

Notice that I made the property depend on analyses.@each.timeAnalyzed - this tells ember that whenever the timeAnalyzed changes on any of the analyses, it will recompute to find the mostImportantAnalysis again.

This means that, while the analyses are still a promise, mostImportantAnalysis will be null, but as soon as the promise resolves, all the timeAnalyzed's will change and the mostImportantAnalysis will be computed.

For your actual implementation, you can add any fields which you use to determine what the most important analysis is to the property() function call eg:

property('analyses.@each.timeAnalyzed', 'analyses.@each.agent', 'approach', 'instrument' )

For examples with more simple computation, you can use Ember computed property macros:
  http://eviltrout.com/2013/07/07/computed-property-macros.html
  http://emberjs.com/api/ (see the apis for the various computed macros)

Note: I'm not 100% sure if this function will run before the promise resolves, but if it does you may have to do a nullcheck to avoid an error.